# Messing with several versions of drush

Tags: drush

When I run

```bash
drush --version
```

I get next output:

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
 Drush Version   :  7.4.0
```

For getting rid of the warning, I have been told I to install drush version 8.
So I issued:

```
composer require drush/drush:8
```

giving next result:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drush/drush
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
9 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

So I suppose drush was already at version 8, but issuing the command above, I still have the same result: version 7.4.0. I am probably messing with several versions of drush.

I would like to understand better how to get rid of the old version, and being sure I am using the last one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123460/discussion-between-pierre-francois-and-leymannx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the globally installed Drush with a locally installed Drush. To run the local Drush from your project, run `vendor/drush/drush/drush --version` from inside your project. This will give you 8.0.0 which is a bit old. Better get the latest Drush 8 release with `composer require drush/drush:^8`. Currently this is Drush 8.4.8.

Next, you can consider to either update the globally installed Drush (not recommended) `composer global require drush/drush:^8` or alternatively (recommended) install the [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) instead. The Drush Launcher is just a wrapper command to always pick up the project-local Drush. So you can easily run Composer-based D7 and D8/D8+ projects on the same machine in parallel and calling `drush --version` in a project will adjust accordingly.

If your project is D8 or D9 install Drush 10 instead `composer require drush/drush`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved my problem after trying a lot of things to upgrade composer and drush and finally crashing completely:

```bash
cd $HOME                                           # the current directory must be $HOME
rm -rf .composer                                   # remove all composer packages 
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php    # install composer in $HOME
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer            # move composer from local to global 
composer -W global require drush/drush:^8.4        # install the version of drush I need
```

Voilà.

After this, the executable `composer.phar` is renamed to `composer`. So do not longer look at `$HOME/composer.phar` if you ever want to uninstall it. You will just have to delete `/usr/bin/composer`.

Check your $PATH: `$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin` must be included. Caution: some configurations have `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` in the $PATH variable, which is also possible, but you need to keep it coherent with the place where the packages are installed.

Comment: Where is the (global) executable of drush?

Comment: `~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush` and I think a symlink at `~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush`. Most people add `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to their $PATH.

Comment: I found it in `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin` with a symlink to `../drush/drush/drush`, i.e. `~/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush`